# Should I be using AFP or SMB?

Tags: macos, smb, afp

I know that Apple has made SMB the default network protocol for a few releases now.  However is there any benefits of using AFP?  Is there anything I can do on a AFP volume that I can't do on a SMB volume?

I do know that if I connect my Synology with AFP I can have a custom icon for the volume.  However with SMB I can't.  So I'm wondering if there's anything else that I lose with SMB?

Comment: I believe Time Machine backups via OSX server only work via AFP so you have to use it with some NAS systems for that alone. There's some info in this Ars Technica article about it in more detail: 
http://arstechnica.com/apple/2014/11/a-power-users-guide-to-os-x-server-yosemite-edition/5/