# Does macOS Sierra support Server Side Copy via SMB and/or AFP?

Tags: afp, smb, freenas

I'm using FreeNAS and it has the option to share data using SMB or AFP. Since I recently learned that [AFP is being deprecated](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/285417/is-afp-slated-to-be-removed-from-future-versions-of-macos), I'm hesitant to use AFP but I'v read that [AFP supports Server Side Copy](https://serverfault.com/questions/566708/which-file-transfer-protocols-support-server-side-copying) and [SMB on Mac does not](https://forums.freenas.org/index.php?threads/moving-files-and-folders-from-client.54992/).

I want to confirm both points with the Ask Different crowd:

1. Does macOS Sierra connecting to a FreeNAS server via AFP support Server Side Copy?
2. Does macOS Sierra connecting to a FreeNAS server via SMB support Server Side Copy?

Based on [release notes](http://www.freenas.org/blog/announcing-freenas-9-2-1-1-release/), FreeNAS supports Samba 4.1.4 (SMB3), and thus supports Server-Side Copy when connect with compatible clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Unfortunately, the source code of the AFP driver is not free software, so it's difficult to give a definitive answer on that. However, it appears that [Netatalk supports copyfile](https://sourceforge.net/p/netatalk/code/ci/bd53044732775db0445f128294ffd0ffbe46c54e/tree/etc/afpd/file.c#l1258), so it's likely that the answer to that question is yes.
2. If you look at the [source code](https://opensource.apple.com/source/smb/smb-759.40.1/kernel/smbfs/smbfs_vnops.c.auto.html) of the latest version of the macOS smbfs driver, you can see that it does implement the copyfile operation (see smbfs_vnop_copyfile)

   According to the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/HardwareDrivers/RN-SMB/), OS X did that since ca. 2013:

   > 8) Added Server Side Copies (OS X SMB Client <-> OS X/Windows SMB File
   >   Server)

   Whether that actually gets used with FreeNAS, I cannot tell - I have no access to a FreeNAS system.

Comment: Strange, in my initial testing, it didn't appear to work but trying again, I can verify that server-side copy works using macOS Sierra connecting to FreeNAS via SMB.