# OS X 10.12.16: "URLs with the type 'afp:' are not supported"

Tags: time-machine, afp

I am mounting an AFP volume hosted on a FreeBSD server using `netatalk`. I am able to successfully mount the volume using `mount_afp`. However, I am mounting it for the purposes of Time Machine, and it seems that unfortunately `mount_afp` changes the permissions of the mount directory to `700`, `root:wheel` so that the user is unable to access it.

So I am trying to mount the volume normally from Finder, unsuccessfully, with the above error code.

The URL I am using to mount it is
`afp://user:pass@server/VolumeName`

Comment: Are you using [`netatalk`](https://www.freshports.org/net/netatalk/) (deprecated) or [`netatalk3`](https://www.freshports.org/net/netatalk3/)?  That said.... since Apple [deprecated AFP](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/285419/119271), I've only used SMB2 for all my shares on BSD.

Comment: It was [cmd]netatalk[/cmd]. It was an old installation so didn't think to try to upgrade. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I have discovered that AFP is now deprecated, and that I will need to turn to other mechanisms to provide the remote Time Machine. I presume this is the reason for this error message.

Comment: AFP is deprecated, but should still work. TM still uses AFP on Mojave.

Comment: I see. Well, the system did give the error about the unsupported scheme, so I guess something is wrong. But not a concern of mine now. Thanks